# If file contains search string how to get it

Tags: java

Hi I wrote a function that reads all lines of a file, I need to search a line from this log file. This log file adds timestamp at the beginning i.e.

`2019/04/26 20:37:47 --  Searching this line`

```
public static boolean containsLine(String line) {
        BufferedReader br = null;
        Reader reader = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        boolean isInstalled = false;
        List<String> fileOutput = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            String searchLine;
            is = new FileInputStream(logFile);
            reader = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8");
            br = new BufferedReader(reader);

            while ((searchLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                fileOutput.add(searchLine);
            }

            if (fileOutput.contains(line)) {
                isInstalled = true;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if (is != null) {
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return isInstalled;
    }
```

How can I get a true if the file contains String `Searching this line` I would like get all strings beside the date. Is there any way to do that? Or is there a better way to check if file contains line we're looking for.

Comment: Did you try the obvious? `String.contains()`?

Comment: @jbx thanks it works :D

Comment: @Gstart OK, check my answer though, because your method is very inefficient (and unnecessarily long and complicated)

Answer (score 3):

Your method is quite inefficient on memory, especially if your log files can become huge. 
What about something simple like:

```
public static boolean containsLine(File logFile, String line) {
  try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(logFile.toPath())) {
    return stream.anyMatch(fullLine-> fullLine.contains(line));
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return false;
  }
}
```

This loads the file lazily, and the moment it finds the `String` it stops, without going through all the rest of the lines.

If you have large files you can even see if you manage to speed it up by doing `stream.parallel.anyMatch(...)`.

If you are on an ancient JDK that doesn't support streams, you can still replicate it in the same way, if you modify your code a bit. Rather than loading all the lines of your file in an array, you can just replace you while loop with this:

```
  while ((searchLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if (searchLine.contains(line)) {
       return true;
    }
  }
```

And remove the array and any code related to it, and in the end `return false;`. 
This way if the line you are searching for is the first line you don't process the rest of the file for nothing.

Comment: I need something compile with Java 6, I am not able to use streams. So I decided to wrote a method as above. Is there anyway to improve it?

Comment: @Gstark OMG JDK 6 is ancient. OK updated my answer, you can fix your function so that it doesnt read the rest of the file when it finds the search string.